# What difference does round brackets in regular expression make?

Tags: python, regex

I am currently going through pythonchallenge.com, and now trying to make a code that searches for a lowercase letter with exactly three uppercase letters on both side of it. Then I got stuck on trying to make a regular expression for it. This is what I have tried:

```
import re
#text is in https://pastebin.com/pAFrenWN since it is too long
p = re.compile("[^A-Z]+[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}[^A-Z]+")
print("".join(p.findall(text)))
```

This is what I got with it:
dqIQNlQSLidbzeOEKiVEYjxwaZADnMCZqewaebZUTkLYNgouCNDeHSBjgsgnkOIXdKBFhdXJVlGZVme
gZAGiLQZxjvCJAsACFlgfe
qKWGtIDCjn

I later searched for the solution, which had this regular expression:

```
p = re.compile("[^A-Z]+[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[^A-Z]+")
```

So there is a bracket around [a-z], and I couldn't figure out what difference it makes. I would like some explanation on this.

Comment: `{3}` is the previous expression has to be found 3 times.  `[A-Z]{3}` is the same than `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]`

Comment: @DanB The OP isn't talking about `{3}`; they are referring to `[a-z]` Vs `([a-z])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing By placing part of a
>   regular expression inside round brackets or parentheses, you can group
>   that part of the regular expression together. This allows you to apply
>   a quantifier to the entire group or to restrict alternation to part of
>   the regex.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Basicly the regex engine can find a list of strings matching the whole search pattern, and return you the parts inside the ().

Comment: Damn, it was that simple.